# Filter ACK packets

Tags: tcpdump

I have the following `tcpdump -i eth0 -w pkts.pcap -n tcp port 5000` to filter every packet flowing between 2 hosts. However, one of the hosts always sends an ACK.

How do I filter the ACKs too, so my pkts.pcap does not show them?

Answer (score 2):

`tcpdump -i eth0 -w pkts.pcap -n "tcp port 5000 and tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-ack) = 0"` will result in SYN and RST packets being deposited in `pkts.pcap`.

Comment: Excellent example of using header flags for filtering